# How can I convert a SQL query with Row Number to Lambda Expressions For EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, devextreme

I have a .net core mvc application with devextreme DataGrid with EntityFrameworkCore Version="7.0.9"

And I have this query that I need to show it in a DataGrid

The purpose of this query is to get a list of the machine hours that the next maintenance is based on the last maintenance made for certain periods of the equipment maintained in a factory.

And it works well:

```
SELECT
    E.Id,
    E.Location,
    E.MachineHour,
    M.PeriodHour,
    M.MachineHour AS MaintenanceMachineHour,
    M.MachineHour + M.PeriodHour AS NextMaintenance,
    M.MachineHour + M.PeriodHour - E.MachineHour AS HoursLeft
FROM
    Equipments E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        MN.EquipmentId,
        MN.PeriodId,
        MN.MachineHour,
        MN.MaintenanceDate AS LastMaintenanceDate,
        MP.PeriodHour,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MN.EquipmentId, MN.PeriodId ORDER BY MN.MaintenanceDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        Maintenances MN
    JOIN MaintenancePeriods MP ON MP.Id = MN.PeriodId
) M ON E.Id = M.EquipmentId AND M.RowNum = 1
WHERE
    M.PeriodHour IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    E.Location, M.PeriodHour;
```

so I created a model to hold the data.

```
 public class NextMaintenance_ViewModel
    {
        public Guid? EquipmentId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Ekipman")]
        public string? Location { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Makine Saati")]
        public int? MachineHour { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Bakım Periyodu")]
        public int? PeriodHour { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Bakım Yapılan Saat")]
        public int? MaintenanceMachineHour { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Sonraki Bakım Saati")]
        public int? NextMaintenance { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Kalan Saat")]
        public int? HoursLeft { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is my DataGrid in view:

```
  @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<WorkSpace.Models.Maintenance.NextMaintenance_ViewModel>()
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.Mvc()
                    .Controller("MachineHourLogs")
                    .LoadAction("GetNextMaintenancesList")                    
                    )
                    .FilterRow(filterRow => filterRow
                    .Visible(true)
                    .ApplyFilter(GridApplyFilterMode.Auto)
                    )
                    .SearchPanel(searchPanel => searchPanel
                    .Visible(true)
                    .Width(240)
                    .Placeholder("Ara...")
                    )
                    .HeaderFilter(headerFilter => headerFilter.Visible(true))
                    .Scrolling(scrolling => scrolling.Mode(GridScrollingMode.Standard))
                    .ShowRowLines(true)
                    .RowAlternationEnabled(true)
                    .ShowBorders(true)
                    .RemoteOperations(true)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.Location);
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.MachineHour);
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.PeriodHour);
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.MaintenanceMachineHour);
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.NextMaintenance);
                        columns.AddFor(m => m.HoursLeft);

                }
            )
       )
```

I have tried this method in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NextMaintenance_ViewModel>> GetNextMaintenancesList()
        {
            var result = _context.Equipments
                .SelectMany(e => e.Maintenances
                    .Where(m => m.PeriodId != null)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.MaintenanceDate)
                    .Select(m => new NextMaintenance_ViewModel
                    {
                        EquipmentId = e.Id,
                        Location = e.Location,
                        MachineHour = e.MachineHour,
                        PeriodHour = m.Period.PeriodHour,
                        MaintenanceMachineHour = m.MachineHour,
                        NextMaintenance = m.MachineHour + m.Period.PeriodHour,
                        HoursLeft = m.MachineHour + m.Period.PeriodHour - e.MachineHour
                    })
                    .Take(5) // ???
                )
                .Where(e => e.PeriodHour > 0) 
                .OrderBy(e => e.Location)
                .ThenBy(e => e.PeriodHour)
                .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

I could not find a proper way for this.

Does anyone have an idea for it?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core allows you to drop down to SQL queries when working with a relational database. SQL queries are useful if the query you want can't be expressed using LINQ, or if a LINQ query causes EF to generate inefficient SQL.

So, you can try to use [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql) to begin a LINQ query based on a SQL query, like this:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

Or you can create a Stored procedure, and then execute it using the FromSql. Like this:

```
var students = context.Students.FromSql("GetStudents 'Bill'").ToList();
```

More detail information, see :

[SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries)

[Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/raw-sql-queries-in-ef-core.aspx)

[Working with Stored Procedure in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx)

[How to call stored procedure procedure using entity framework core?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1326708/how-to-call-stored-procedure-procedure-using-entit)

Comment: Yea I did it with Raw Sql Query. But this method increases the dependency with the database.